# webview not download file from servlet response

Tags: java, android, webview

I want download a file with webview when I click of button on page servlet post data.  The request url is like website.com/download.htm. This url response contains file url as attachment but nothing happens and I see this response in Chrome remote debugging tools:

```
Response Headers
Cache-Control:post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=1436366157805NANItmuPUnKWRaQO.xls
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en-US
Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel
Date:Wed, 08 Jul 2015 14:35:57 GMT
Expires:0
Keep-Alive:timeout=10, max=35
Pragma:public
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.0
cookies:[]
content: {
size: 0,
mimeType: application/octet-stream,
compression: 403
},
redirectURL: ,
headersSize: 403,
bodySize: -403,
_transferSize:
```

I am not the owner of the servlet page, here is my app code:

```
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSetting.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            getWindow().setTitle(title);
        }
    });
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.d("error", "" + errorCode + description + failingUrl);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Log.d("started", url);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d('url', url);
            return false;
        }

        web.loadUrl("https://website.com");
        web.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart (String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
            long contentLength)
            {
                Log.d("download", url + "\n" + mimetype + contentDisposition + contentLength);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                final String[] separated = url.split("/");
                final String myFile = separated[separated.length - 1];
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, myFile);
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            }
        });

    });
```

I checked website with chrome and stock browser the file is downloaded fine but not on webview, and I checked different websites for downloading files; webview downloads file on other websites with a direct url. Download listener does not work on that url.  I see the website.com/download.htm in logcat in onPagestarted and onPagefinish but not on  shouldOverrideUrlLoading.  Other pages are shown on all three function. What is the problem?

Comment: Have you made any progress on this issue? I have a similar problem and I think it comes from `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` not supported by chromium. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/YJzAjcAx1z0

Comment: no i drop this project